# iOS 5 issue with MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have the following code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]];
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
//create a NSNotificationCenter which call moviePlaybackComplete function when movie duration available

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:) name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:moviePlayer];

(void) movieDurationAvailable:(NSNotification *)notification  
{
NSLog(@"duration of movie : %f", [moviePlayerController duration]);
}
```

The method called movieDurationAvailable never gets called.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You are not starting the download / playback -- try `[moviePlayer prepareToPlay]`

Comment: How about a plain [moviePlayer play]? I must confess, I did never rely on that notification but simply used whatever value was returned by the MPMoviePlayerController. In my implementations, this was done on a timed basis (e.g. every 0.5secs). So, when the player decides to revise the estimated playtime, my App would benefit from that correction.

Comment: What if I need to get the movie duration by not starting the movie?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ARC the notification won't get called because moviePlayer probably is dealloc'ed as soon as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

66replica is correct.  Declare moviePlayer in the .h file instead and add the [moviePlayer play] to your code above to solve the problem.